# Тип данных для color

Tags: java, android

Доброго времени суток. Имеется кастомный `listview`, внутри два `textview`. Требуется изменить цвет одного из `textview`. Цвет хранится в ресурсах вида `#363636`. Из `MainActivity` пробовал передавать цвет в адаптер типами `int` и `String`, но цвет не менялся. Может я тип неправильно выбрал или считывать как то его надо по другому? Не знаю какой вид надо посылать на `.setTextColor();`. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пусть в colors.xml содержится необходимый цвет:

```
<color name="colorRed">#FF0000</color>
```

Пусть также имеется некоторый `TextView`:

```
private TextView mTextView;
```

Тогда, установить цвет текста данного `TextView` можно таким образом:

```
mTextView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorRed));
```

**Upd.**
Получение цвета:

```
int redColor = ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorRed);
```

Comment: Подскажите, а как присвоить переменной этот цвет, т.к мне нужно эту переменную передать в адаптер?

Comment: @Pollux, А Вы уверены, что Вам нужно передавать этот цвет в адаптер? Может все-таки взять этот цвет из `colors.xml` прямо в адаптере?

Но если Вы все-таки очень хотите передать цвет в адаптер, то смотрите Upd к ответу.

Comment: Дело в том, что делаю дневную/ночную схему для приложения, поэтому передаю в адаптер для новой отрисовки.

Comment: @Pollux, А если в зависимости от темы необходимо изменять более одного цвета? Можете оповещать адаптер о необходимой теме, а уже в адаптере, исходя из темы, инициализировать цвета.

Comment: Согласен, можно и так. Но меняется только один цвет, да и к тому же я так понимаю Вы имеете ввиду стили, а там я не сильно силен)

Answer (score 2):

Решил для себя проблему так: установил тип `int` для `color_text` и передавал цвет не из ресурсов, а из кода вот так: `color_text = Color.parseColor("#2B2B2B");`. Тогда все сработало как надо.